# Specification for the 'top level' Material 3 transition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm trying to implement the [top level](https://m3.material.io/styles/motion/transitions/transition-patterns#8327d206-2a7d-423a-abf0-2be86130535b) transition from Material 3 in a Compose project, but there don't seem to be any specifications on how it should act. I've tried looking at the source for the MDC version of it, but that doesn't seem to be super helpful. [The Material 2 site](https://m2.material.io/design/motion/the-motion-system.html#fade-through) gives a better idea of what it should be like, but I think it's changed somewhat based on the description. I've tried:

```kotlin
enterTransition = {
   fadeIn(
      tween(300, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
   ) + scaleIn(initialScale = 0.92f)
},
exitTransition = {
   fadeOut(tween(200, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing))
}
```

Is there some kind of specification which explains what the animation should consist of?